# UIButton: primaryActionTriggered vs. touchUpInside

Tags: swift, uibutton, uikit

basically I was wondering what's the difference between the `.primaryActionTriggered` and `.touchUpInside` controlEvents for `UIButton` since they seem to be triggered similarly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.primaryActionTriggered` is not limited to buttons, but to controls in general.

For most controls, it will trigger on `.valueChanged`, except for `UIButton`, where it is for `.touchUpInside`, and for `UITextField` where it is `.didEndOnExit`.

Comment: is there a list of all of them, or is this comprehensive? :)

Comment: What list do you need?

Comment: I was wondering what the primary action of each control would be if it was published, but it seems it's a bit of a fools errand anyways. I was trying to match Events to disambiguate and distribute some behavior, but it seems that when one registers for an event, the events that are passed to that function aren't necessarily the event you subscribed to, nor do they contain it, went with a workaround, but your answer still helped, thanks